# For Recipient how do I store Sender's account address and Password of Recipient's own account in hashed from?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, contract-design, hash, password

How to check following things using Solidity:

- Password matching (hash formed)
- if password matches then transfer take place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No data on the Ethereum blockchain should be considered private, so storing something like passwords is a bad idea, even in hashed form.

However, when a user sends a transaction to a smart contract, you can be ensured that it's actually coming from that user, since they need to have the private key in order to send a transaction.

In that way, Ethereum itself acts as an authentication layer, removing the need to store passwords for authentication.

You can combine this with some form of authorisation by storing a list or a mapping of Ethereum accounts that are authorised to send transactions or execute other operations on the smart contract.

Comment: Thank you... Totally agree with your answer that there is no need for password for Authentication. But I wanted to write a contract for Buyer - Seller, in which I want to use password, so whenever the product is delivered to Buyer he/she will send password to seller and then seller can release or withdraw predefined amount of payment.

Comment: What I have to do to fulfill above procedure?

Comment: What is the use case of the password in this scenario? The buyer can send a confirmation transaction to indicate that they received it, or something similar. However, the difficult thing in a dapp such as that will be conflict resolution, e.g. what happens when the seller says they sent the item, and the buyer says they never received it. I don't have a clear answer to creating a production-worthy marketplace dapp, but I don't see the use case of the password here.